# What is the real value of Metaplex Candy Machine? Why do we need it? What is a Collection?

Tags: metaplex, nft, candy

When I first came to Solana. I was surprised at the difficulty in answering what I expected to be a straightforward query.

How do I find the nfts in a collection?

On EVM chains. Programs are stateful. They don't necessarily need to be, but they can be and generally are. This makes a given program, less re-usable. Because You may want to use the same logic, but with different state.

Solana separates state from logic and I love it for that.

But one sort of natural consequence of the stateful and duplicated programs on EVM chains, is that collections tend to have a 1:1 relationship with collection management programs.

See Tokens on Solana are also contextualized within the program that governs them. But due to the improved re-usability of Solana programs, everyone is using the same program. Which means everyone is using the same context. We're all in one giant collection.

Which presented us with a problem unique to Solana. How do I find the subset of nfts that are in MY collection, rather than this "global" collection.

I think the proper solution, with some foresight, and consideration, and reflection, would have been to have nfts have "parents".  And in any relational database, the "child entity" in a "parent child" relationship, observed the parent. This scales better, as it adds one extra field to each child, rather than "n" additional fields to the parent.

But I don't think the founding fathers had considered the implications of all of this when they defined the SPL Token Program. That the side effect of having a program that is properly architect, is that it may break assumptions and workflows built around the artifacts of poorly architected alternatives that were mainstream.

Anyhow, we very quickly ended up with "token lists" This is the equivalent of the "n additional" fields approach above. Where the list has to be aware of all of the nfts, instead of the other way around.

But these token lists , for the obvious scaling reasons I mentioned above, were impractical to contend with at scale.

There were several problems. How do we get the list on chain so that the collection membership isn't being held privately off chain? How do we populate it in an automated fashion? How do we validate the authenticity of it?

And I think the first efforts were just around building these lists in an automated way an getting the collections built, on chain and verified.

But this was largely coming from the perspective of a lot of people having existing collections they needed to get processed, and the solution I think reflects that. The early solutions were geared around large taking existing tokens, and getting them "collectioned" and "verified" retroactively and in bulk.

It's not that retroactively adding nfts to collections is the best route, it's that it was the need we had at the time.

But if you take a moment to step back and think about the ideal way to do collection addition, it would be, atomically, JIT, on the fly, lazily, at the time of nft mint, ideally that mint would instantly be, a verified member of the collection.  This is after all, the side effect benefit, of minting nfts into a stateful collection manager on an EVM chain.

This is where Metaplex Candy Machine comes in to play. Suddenly, your purchasers could mint nfts, and you didn't have to followup with a long expensive batch, run on a cron or manually, to bring everyone into your collection.

The way Metaplex solved this, was in allowing a program to auto authorize an NFT into your collection as long as it met some minimum criteria and there were slots available.  People could now self serve.

Of course, metaplex candy machine also does tons of other stuff for you. Gobs of other things you might say.

Which then brings me to my question. At its core, what is Metaplex Candymachine, and why do we need it?

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR Answer

Candy Machine enables **"Atomic Mint To Collection"**. This was the need that made Candy Machine essential.

Before candy machine, adding NFTs required two actions, completed by two different acting parties.

1. The NFT purchaser minted the token.
2. The collection manager then had to follow up, in order to add the minted token to the collection. This caused the collection manager to be actively involved for every mint.

**Candy Machine eliminates that second step. And the scaling implications it had on the collection manager**

Fluffy Answer

Candy Machine does not spit out your NFTs as its name implies. At least, that's not where its true value lies. It's also not that its a container for your candy colored tokens.

**Candy machine is not for getting candy. Candy Machine is for adding candy.**

The real value of Metaplex Candy Machine is in its ability to enable and empower token minters to self register their tokens as part of the collection, taking that burden off the collection managers hands, so long as the token meets some minimum criteria.

That's it. The real core of candy machine. The real reason we need it, is because it allows NFTs to be added to the target collection and be automatically verified, as long as they meet criteria, and there are slots available on the machine.

It eliminates the need for costly or complex "retrofit" jobs to add the nfts to the collection in post.

And importantly it allows NFTs to be atomically added to the machine with a single signer, in a single transaction.

Metaplex candy machine does a whole lot of other things. And I think that teams should evaluate those other features to see if they are really needed. Because it may be that your team only needs automated, atomic, single signer, verified collection registration, with onboarding criteria. If that's all you need, candy machine may be more complexity than it is value add.  Additionally, you may want to establish a different set of criteria, for onboarding an NFT, than what metaplex has defined, and you may want different authority configurations for your tokens once they are added.

It would be nice to see if we can iterate on the groundwork Metaplex has laid, and build something more portable, and more singular in concern, that only supports, this atomic, single transaction, single signer, verified collection linking for any NFT that meets a defined set of criteria.

I think that more "general" concern, being addressed independently of candy machine's other numerous features, may reduce the barrier to entry for new teams and developers.

All we need is a program, with "verify" rights for the collection that says.

**Pseudo Code Answer**

```
setCollectionAndVerify(token, tokenOwnershipAccount, collection, tokenMetadataAccount)
if(!collectionHasAvailableSlots(collection)) throw
if(!matchesTokenCriteria(token, collection)) throw
if(!matchesTokenOwnershipAccountCriteria(tokenOwnershipAccount, collection)) throw
_setCollectionAndSignVerified(tokenMetadataAccount, collection)
_setCollectionSpecifiedAuthorityChanges(token,tokenMetadataAccount,collection)
_populateMetdataWithCollectionDefaults(tokenMetadataAccount,collection)
```

Note that this pseudocode solution still takes advantage of Metaplex's metadata account. I think the metadata spec is great. We're just trying to provide an alternative, lower barrier to entry, and perhaps more customizable alternative to Candy Machine.

Comment: Would be great of the answer could be a bit more concise and to the point. After reading, it leaves me confused and I forgot what was in there in the beginning. :-)

Comment: You don't need it, you can deploy your own contract and mint your collection. The use of the Candy Machine is not mandatory, is another option.

But, one option that makes the job easy for creators, because setting up a Candy Machine is easy, and it comes with whitelist features, hidden settings, different storage, etc.

You can get all the NFT of one collection by just querying the Metaplex Certified Collection. Or, using your Candy Machine ID that you get when creating a Candy Machine (not the Candy Machine program address).